# Вылетает при удалении памяти

Tags: c++, c, динамические-массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void MergeSort(float* arrayPtr, int left, int right)
{
    if (left == right) return; // границы сомкнулись
    int middle = (left + right) / 2; // середина последовательности
    // рекурсивно вызываем функцию сортировки для каждой половины
    MergeSort(arrayPtr, left, middle);
    MergeSort(arrayPtr, middle + 1, right);

    int i = left;  // начало первого пути
    int j = middle + 1; // начало второго пути
    float* bufer = new float[right]; // дополнительный массив
    for (int i = 0; i < right; i++) bufer[i] = 0;
    for (int step = 0; step < right - left + 1; step++)
    {
        // записываем в формируемую последовательность меньший из элементов двух путей или остаток первого пути если j > r
        if ((j > right) || ((i <= middle) && (arrayPtr[i] < arrayPtr[j])))
        {
            bufer[step] = arrayPtr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            bufer[step] = arrayPtr[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    // переписываем сформированную последовательность в исходный массив
    for (int step = 0; step < right - left + 1; step++)
        arrayPtr[left + step] = bufer[step];

    if (bufer)
        delete[] bufer;
}

void main() {
    double time = 0; int i;
    int SizeArray = 10;

    float* sorted_array4 = new float[SizeArray];
    for (i = 0; i < SizeArray; i++)
    {
        sorted_array4[i] = static_cast<float>(rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / 20)) - 10; // заполняем массив случайными числами в диапазон (-10;10)
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        auto t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        MergeSort(sorted_array4, 0, SizeArray - 1); // вызов функции сортировки слиянием
        auto t2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        unsigned int Time = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
        time += Time;
    }
    time = time / 10;
    cout << "Массив № элементов) || Сортировка слиянием с общим буфером || Среднее время = " << time << " микросекунд" << endl;
    time = 0;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Возможно выход за пределы массива. Только где именно не так просто понять. Попробуйте закомментировать блоки `for` по порядку и посмотрите не исчезнет ли ошибка. Если исчезнет, значит в этом блоке ищите выход за пределы массива. Ну первый блок это просто инициализация, а во втором или третьем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 2):

классика - выход за пределы массива. в выражении `right - left + 1` когда left равно 0, right+1 даст возможность записать в элемент сразу за последним. Скорее всего (но я не уверен), нужно просто вместо `right - left + 1` писать `right - left` - оно не падает.

И в самом конце освободить массив sorted_array4.

Также, если уже пишите chrono, то пишите `int main()`, а не `void main()`. Ну и хорошо бы std::vector использовать, а не ручное управление памятью.